# sendBeacon request stuck as "(pending)" when attached to unload event

Tags: javascript

When I call navigator.sendBeacon directly in the console, I immediately see the request in the Chrome dev tools Network pane complete successfully.

When I use code like what's below to attach sendBeacon to the beforeunload event and then navigate away from the page, I see a row added to the Network pane but its status stays stuck at "(pending)" and never sends.

What am I doing wrong?

```
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    navigator.sendBeacon(
      'https://www.example.com/sendBeacon-data-collector',
      'Sent by a beacon!');
  }, false);
```

Comment: The same issue for me. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 9):

You say that the connection is stuck at "pending" and that it never sends. If it did not send, the connection would not at all show in the network pane, so this confirms that it **does** indeed send.

As for the status being stuck at "pending" that seems to be expected behaviour (a claim that I established empirically by observation only). By definition the sendBeacon command is not expecting an answer, so I assume that it's just normal that the browser does not show if the connection worked or not as it never reads a possible reply from the server (pure speculation on my part).

Anyway: I've got a sendBeacon in my web app that saves the last data to the database which is working fine in spite of the "pending" status prevailing. So if your data does not arrive, the problem may lie somewhere else.

For instance you need to make sure you send the data in the right format. In order to make it compatible with a script reading data from an HTML form, you cannot simply send a JSON string, but you need to put the string into formdata (otherwise you can only get it from raw post data on server side)

Example:

```
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('data', JSON.stringify(beaconData));
    navigator.sendBeacon("inc/php/saveData.php", fd);
```

Also you need to be aware that sendBeacon always sends the data via POST parameters. If you want to use GET you need to add the data yourself in the url.

Comment: I'm not sure that the data is send as you mention, I have the same problem and network log says: `Method: POST; Status:(Pending);Size: 0B;Time Pending;Queued at 0;Started at 0;Conection Start: Stalled` I guess this means that the connection never start.

Comment: In my case it did send for sure: I had the PHP script write the data out to a text file, so I could verify that it was received by the server.

Comment: could it be due I'm using it on an angular4 SPA?

Comment: Unfortunately I have never worked with any version of Angular, so I can't even make an educated guess on this. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, when you fire a `navigator.sendBeacon()`, you do not expect to receive any response from the server. You merely "queue" the request to be made by the browser before your page unloads completely.

One way to check if your request was queued properly is to see if the `sendBeacon()` method has returns `true` or `false`. If `true`, your request was queued properly and should be guaranteed to be run by the browser. If `false`, then it was not queued properly. See this [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon#Return_values) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I had a Node/Express server that I was using to collect the record of the request. I was testing with an without the data.

The data can be sent as ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob, DOMString, FormData, or URLSearchParams object. So, that was not the issue.

The problem was in my server. I was using `app.get( )` to check for the request instead of `app.post( )`.

ALL sendBeacon requests are sent via POST.

They will always appear as pending in the Chrome dev tools network tab.
They will always show that there was a text/html response which is empty.

The sendBeacon request will be sent though via POST. It can be triggered via "unload" OR "beforeunload".

Comment: Can you please provide a source for `They will always appear as pending in the Chrome dev tools network tab. They will always show that there was a text/html response which is empty.`. That is roughly what the other answers say and what the bounty is being offered for.

Comment: Here is the tutorial I did on the topic - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmoolce6uDo

Comment: Privacy settings don't allow viewing of that.

Comment: Sorry. The video is scheduled to launch on Wednesday. Thought I had released it last week. It explains the same things that I said above but in more detail. Here is the spec. for sendBeacon - https://www.w3.org/TR/beacon/#sec-sendBeacon-method. In the NOTE section it says that the server will not provide a response.  The "pending" status is what Chrome displays to mean that a request was started but nothing has come back yet.